# How to select multiple columns with entity framework and display it with textBlocks?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to select multiple columsn from tblGames and then display it on a textblock. But i can only display it for one how would i do this for multiple columns.

Code:

```
string Name = _db
    .tblGames
    .Where(u => u.GameID == 1)
    .Select(u => u.Title)
    .SingleOrDefault();

tb_GameTitle_GP.Text = Name;
```

Comment: replace this ``Select(u => u.Title)`` by ``Select(u => new {Title = u.Title, Column2 = u.Column2})``, will give you a object

Comment: @MohammedSAJID that gives me error.

Comment: you need to change the ``string`` type to ``var`` or to your custom class. can you put an example of the new ``Text`` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the entity itself:

```
var game = _db
    .tblGames
    .FirstOrDefault(u => u.GameID == 1);
```

...and then access any of its properties:

```
tb_GameTitle_GP.Text = game.Title;
tb_GameId.Text = game.GameID.ToString();
...
```

Comment: is their any way you could also display and image like this.

Comment: @WoterMelan: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: didnt think that would require a whole new question but whatever and i cant upvote ur answer cuz aint got enough point things cuz poeple keep downvoting me but thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: @WoterMelan: Yes, you can. I just upvoted your question. But anyway, please continue asking questions on Stackoverflow. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var name = _db.tblGames
              .Where(x => x.GameID == 1)
              .Select(x => new YourClassName 
                                  {
                                    Title = x.Title,
                                    Column2 = x.Column2,
                                    Column3 = x.Column3
                                  })
              .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: How would i display each column on different textBlocks.

Comment: nvm im getting this error The entity or complex type 'RareMantisModel.tblGame' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'